# Is the Identity Theorem of complex function still true in Riemann surface?

Tags: complex-analysis

For single-valued analytic function in complex plain, it satisfies the identity theorem. What about an analytic function in Riemann surface (which means the function is probably multi-value at a point with same argument)? Does the identity theorem still remain truth? Thanks very much for the answer.

p.s. the identity theorem for single-valued analytic functions states: given functions $f$ and $g$ analytic on a domain $D$ , if $f = g$ on some ${\displaystyle S\subseteq D}$, where ${\displaystyle S}$  has an accumulation point, then $f = g$ on $D$.

Comment: You should add what is meant by “uniqueness theorem”. Specifically, did you mean [the identity theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)?

Comment: @FShrike yes, you are right. I have corrected the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have probably found the answer of my question. It has shown in wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem_for_Riemann_surfaces.

Let ${\displaystyle X}$ and ${\displaystyle Y}$ be Riemann surfaces, let ${\displaystyle X}$ be connected, and let ${\displaystyle f,g:X\to Y}$ be holomorphic. Suppose that ${\displaystyle f|_{A}=g|_{A}}$ for some subset $A\subseteq X$ that has a limit point, where ${\displaystyle f|_{A}:A\to Y}$ denotes the restriction of ${\displaystyle f}$ to ${\displaystyle A}$. Then $f = g$ (on the whole of $X$).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1804771)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for your advice.